# 2sxc module in dnn9 editing a template

Tags: 2sxc, dnn9

I am using the person template for a contact page not a contact form and the template is 3 people wide which is causing a word wrap to happen on the first persons information, I am not sure where to edit the code to remove the second and third person from this and also add extra lines of information to display for the clients contact info, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like some basic styling / bootstrap issue. Best also add some screenshots so people can help.